# Option clash for package graphicx

Tags: option-clash

I am facing the above error message. Any who can help me.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}        % В¬В Р„Р°В®Р‡В Р„ТђРІ В¤В«Рї СћР„В«РѕР·ТђВ­РЃРї Р°РЃР±РіВ­Р„В®Сћ eps Р„В®В¬В В­В¤В®В© 
\includegraphicx{XXX.eps}
\graphicspath{{./pict/}}          
% РЏРіРІРј Р„ Р‡В Р‡Р„Тђ Р± Р°РЃР±РіВ­Р„В В¬РЃ
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
```

Comment: \graphicspath{{./pict/}}                                                                                                    
  the error marked on this portion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Wheres the error message?

Comment: Remove the `[pdftex]` from the graphicx declaration, nowadays you never need it.

Comment: @Bernard Option clash for package graphicx...This is heiglighted on \graphicspath{{./pict/}}

Comment: Also you can not include an image in the preamble, just as you can not have text there